# printing a positive or a negative integer, using user input()

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a recursive function to get the users input and print the correct values. the countup function  will be executed only if the value of n is negative, the recursive function  will then print values staring from the value of n to -1 until reaches 0. the value of n should be given by the user! whichever number the user inputs the program should either call the countup for negative or countdown for positive.

```
def countdown(n):
     n = int(input('enter number: '))

    if n <= 0:
         print('ok')
    else:
         print(n)
          countdown(n-1)



def countup(n):
    countdown(n)
   if a >= 0:
       print('double ok')
   else:
       print('enter number: ')
           newnumb = input()
           new_int = int(newnumb)
                countup(new_int)


 print(countdown())
 countup()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You've got the code and description of what it's supposed to do, which is fine, but you don't actually describe the problem you're having with your code.

Comment: the code is not in running state. Kindly pass the 0 value in countdown & countup function call. I mean to update these command 
print(countdown(0))
 countup(0)
because function require augment

Comment: i apologize for not explaining it correctly, but the program should take the users value and call the countdown function recursively and return all values until it reaches zero, if the number is negative the program should call the countup function and return all values . and if the users value is positive then we print positive and if its negative then we print negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you're trying to create a function that counts from a positive to zero, or from a negative to zero, based on input. If that's what you're looking for, this should do:

```
def countdown(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        print(n-i)

def countup(n):
    for i in reversed(range(n,1)):
        print(n-i)


def countit():
    n = int(input('enter number: '))
    if n<=0:
        countup(n)
    else:
        countdown(n)

countit()
```

Using a function that encompasses both functions works best.

Comment: @junior if you needed a recursive function as indicated in the question you should know that this answer does not use recursion. If that's not a requirement please disregard this comment.

Comment: @junior I'm glad it worked!  Also, if you could mark it as the accepted answer it would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive option:

```
def count(n):
    print n
    if n<0:
        count(n+1)
    elif n>0:
        count(n-1)

n = int(input('enter number: '))
count(n)
```

Comment: your answer is correct as well and I appreciate the help. I intended to use a recursive function to get a better understanding of them but getting the program to work was ultimately the goal. I also included some of your code snippet into another program.